# Paste Multiple Cells of Excel Data into Infopath Form in Sharepoint

Tags: excel, sharepoint, infopath

I've created an Infopath (2010) form with a repeating table to update a Sharepoint (2010) list. A major requirement is the ability for users to copy a line from an Excel spreadsheet and paste the entire line into the repeating table. So, for example, if the repeating table is three columns wide, the user should be able to copy three, adjacent Excel cells from a single row and paste the data into the repeating table row in a single operation.

I've built the form in Infopath Designer, and everything works as expected when I preview the form *in Inforpath Designer* - data from different Excel cells goes into the different fields in the repeating table row. No issues submitting the data.

However, when I publish the form to Sharepoint and attempt to use the form in Internet Explorer 10, the behavior changes. Instead of the three cells being pasted across the three fields of the table, all three datapoints are pasted, separated by tabs, in the first cell of the table. The second and third cells are blank.

Is there some way around this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got this solution.  I have changed the form type in form options. At the compatibility section I selected InfoPath Filler Form instead of web browser form.

Go to File then select Form options.
Select Compatibility in Category.
Change the form type to: InfoPath Filler Form

Once you published the form it should work regardless of your explorer version.